# jQuery UI dialog remembers the first submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bbcode

I am trying to create a simple, non-WYSIWYG bbCode editor using jQuery. My approach is to make it modular, so that I can separately add different buttons with different actions to the editor toolbar. However - as a beginner in JavaScript -, I am facing with a problem.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/hhaG5W2q) is the simplified version of my code, which still produces the bug.

**The dependencies**

- jQuery core
- jQuery UI
- [jQuery selection plugin](http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/)
- a HTML page which has a `<textarea>` of the `bbEditor` class, like [this one](http://pastebin.com/TjigAvV0)

**The problem with the dialog**

The bug is somewhere around my `showUrlDialog()` function. First time, after the page loaded, the insert URL action works fine. But at the following attempts somehow the dialog remembers the first-time given values, and inserts them instead of the currently given values.

My assumption is that the `dialog` object stays in the DOM, but I don't understand, how. It should disappear as the containing `showUrlDialog()` function ends.

Comment: Try `$(this).dialog("destroy");`

Comment: i think you should dispose the dialog after submit or on close event of the dialog.use below given code in close event of dialog to dispose:-$(this).dialog('destroy').remove() or you can pass the id of dialog control in code in place of this. thanks